# RowEditor crashes when maxLength validation is triggered

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, gridpanel, roweditor

I have a Grid with a Row Editing Plugin, within the grid I have one Number Field and maxValue attribute is set to 100 for the field.
However, every time I trigger the maxLength validation, all row editing buttons are crashed and have no responses. I am forced to refresh the page to cancel the row editing mode. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: I would guess that a transparent box around the error message overlays the button, and by moving the error message above the field it could work. If this doesn't help, can you copy your code into a fiddle?

Comment: Do you have extra validation on value change? Maybe you are stuck in a infinite loop?

Comment: Alex: my code is quite long so cannot copy to fiddle, but basically my grid is dynamically reconfigured, and I am not sure if it is the reason that crash the row editing plugin. Michael: I only set a maxValue attribute and allowBlank = false in the number field.